# Extracting the last n characters from a string in R

Tags: r, string, substring

How can I get the last n characters from a string in R?
Is there a function like SQL's RIGHT?

Answer (score 374, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything in base R, but it's straight-forward to make a function to do this using `substr` and `nchar`:

```
x <- "some text in a string"

substrRight <- function(x, n){
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

substrRight(x, 6)
[1] "string"

substrRight(x, 8)
[1] "a string"
```

---

This is vectorised, as @mdsumner points out.  Consider:

```
x <- c("some text in a string", "I really need to learn how to count")
substrRight(x, 6)
[1] "string" " count"
```

Comment: Use stringi package. It works fine with NAs and all encoding :)

Comment: Would it be more efficient to avoid calling `nchar(x)` twice by assigning it to a local variable?

Comment: have been looking for this for a while!

Comment: No mention of which package substrRight is from?

Comment: substrRight is a user defined function from above.

Answer (score 308):

If you don't mind using the `stringr` package, `str_sub` is handy because you can use negatives to count backward:

```
x <- "some text in a string"
str_sub(x,-6,-1)
[1] "string"
```

Or, as Max points out in a comment to this answer,

```
str_sub(x, start= -6)
[1] "string"
```

Comment: also, str_sub(x,start=-n) gets n last characters.

Comment: stringr doesn't work well with NA's value and all encoding. I strongly reccomend stringi package :)

Comment: I believe `stringr` had been remade using `stringi` as a backend, so should work with NAs etc. now.

Answer (score 60):

Use `stri_sub` function from `stringi` package.
To get substring from the end, use negative numbers.
Look below for the examples:

```
stri_sub("abcde",1,3)
[1] "abc"
stri_sub("abcde",1,1)
[1] "a"
stri_sub("abcde",-3,-1)
[1] "cde"
```

You can install this package from github: https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi

It is available on CRAN now, simply type

```
install.packages("stringi")
```

to install this package.

Answer (score 22):

```
str = 'This is an example'
n = 7
result = substr(str,(nchar(str)+1)-n,nchar(str))
print(result)

> [1] "example"
>
```

Answer (score 19):

Another reasonably straightforward way is to use regular expressions and `sub`:

```
sub('.*(?=.$)', '', string, perl=T)
```

So, "get rid of everything followed by one character". To grab more characters off the end, add however many dots in the lookahead assertion:

```
sub('.*(?=.{2}$)', '', string, perl=T)
```

where `.{2}` means `..`, or "any two characters", so meaning "get rid of everything followed by two characters".

```
sub('.*(?=.{3}$)', '', string, perl=T)
```

for three characters, etc. You can set the number of characters to grab with a variable, but you'll have to `paste` the variable value into the regular expression string:

```
n = 3
sub(paste('.+(?=.{', n, '})', sep=''), '', string, perl=T)
```

Comment: To avoid all the look-aheads etc, you could just do `regmatches(x, regexpr(".{6}$", x))`

Answer (score 13):

A simple base R solution using the `substring()` function (who knew this function even existed?):

```
RIGHT = function(x,n){
  substring(x,nchar(x)-n+1)
}
```

This takes advantage of basically being `substr()` underneath but has a default end value of 1,000,000.

Examples:

```
> RIGHT('Hello World!',2)
[1] "d!"
> RIGHT('Hello World!',8)
[1] "o World!"
```

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE**: as noted by [mdsumner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355270/mdsumner), the original code is already vectorised because substr is. Should have been more careful.

And if you want a vectorised version (based on [Andrie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r/7963963#7963963)'s code)

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
  sapply(x, function(xx)
         substr(xx, (nchar(xx)-n+1), nchar(xx))
         )
}

> substrRight(c("12345","ABCDE"),2)
12345 ABCDE
 "45"  "DE"
```

Note that I have changed `(nchar(x)-n)` to `(nchar(x)-n+1)` to get `n` characters.

Comment: I think you mean "`(nchar(x)-n)` to `(nchar(x)-n+1)`"

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
x <- "some text in a string"
n <- 5
substr(x, nchar(x)-n, nchar(x))
```

It shoudl give:

```
[1] "string"
```

Comment: But this returns the last 6 characters not 5

Comment: So perhaps  ...  substr(x, nchar(x)-(n-1), nchar(x))

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to `substr` is to split the string into a list of single characters and process that:

```
N <- 2
sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(x, n) paste(tail(x, n), collapse = ""), N)
```

Comment: I sense a system.time() battle brewing :-)

Answer (score 4):

I use `substr` too, but in a different way. I want to extract the last 6 characters of "Give me your food." Here are the steps:

(1) Split the characters

```
splits <- strsplit("Give me your food.", split = "")
```

(2) Extract the last 6 characters

```
tail(splits[[1]], n=6)
```

Output:

```
[1] " " "f" "o" "o" "d" "."
```

Each of the character can be accessed by `splits[[1]][x]`, where x is 1 to 6.

Answer (score 4):

someone before uses a similar solution to mine, but I find it easier to think as below:

```
> text<-"some text in a string" # we want to have only the last word "string" with 6 letter
> n<-5 #as the last character will be counted with nchar(), here we discount 1
> substr(x=text,start=nchar(text)-n,stop=nchar(text))
```

This will bring the last characters as desired.

Answer (score 4):

For those coming from Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets, you would have seen functions like `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, and `MID()`. I have created a package known as **forstringr** and its development version is currently on [Github](https://github.com/gbganalyst/forstringr).

```
if(!require("devtools")){
 install.packages("devtools")
}

devtools::install_github("gbganalyst/forstringr")

library(forstringr)
```

- the `str_left()`: This counts from the left and then extract n characters
- the `str_right()`- This counts from the right and then extract n characters
- the `str_mid()`- This extract characters from the middle

**Examples:**

```
x <- "some text in a string"

str_left(x, 4)

[1] "some"

str_right(x, 6)

[1] "string"

str_mid(x, 6, 4)

[1] "text"
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to get the last character of a string.

```
    substr(output, nchar(stringOfInterest), nchar(stringOfInterest))
```

You can play with the nchar(stringOfInterest) to figure out how to get last few characters.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification on @Andrie solution gives also the complement:

```
substrR <- function(x, n) { 
  if(n > 0) substr(x, (nchar(x)-n+1), nchar(x)) else substr(x, 1, (nchar(x)+n))
}
x <- "moSvmC20F.5.rda"
substrR(x,-4)
[1] "moSvmC20F.5"
```

That was what I was looking for. And it invites to the left side:

```
substrL <- function(x, n){ 
  if(n > 0) substr(x, 1, n) else substr(x, -n+1, nchar(x))
}
substrL(substrR(x,-4),-2)
[1] "SvmC20F.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if a range of characters need to be picked:

```
# For example, to get the date part from the string

substrRightRange <- function(x, m, n){substr(x, nchar(x)-m+1, nchar(x)-m+n)}

value <- "REGNDATE:20170526RN" 
substrRightRange(value, 10, 8)

[1] "20170526"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base R `substring()` and use `first =` and `last =`.

```
x <- "Just some sample text here"

substring_ex_1 <- substring(x, first = 23, last = 26)
```