# R Extract and combine characters from cell

Tags: r, character, extract, rename

I want to change the time format, which I have as column ("Date") in my data frame ("data"). It is imported from a csv as -Q1 1990- and I would like to have it as -1990Q1-, but my function is not perfect.
I tried:

```
  for (i in 1:length(data$Date)){
    data$Date[i] <- paste(substr(data$Date[i], 4,8),substr(data$Date[i], 1,2),
    sep="")
    }
```

The result is a column in which each row has a NA and I do not know why. Can someone help?
I found already the thread [Extracting the last n characters from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r). In that threat they only mentioned the problem, but did not solve it in an understandable way for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have probably checked this: but just in case what is class(data$Date)?

Comment: In the cells are factors.

Comment: then just use data$Date <- as.character(data$Date) to change to strings. You can change back if needed. I think you will need to tweak your substring calls but I am sure you can do that once you get visual feedback of the result of the paste command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
data$Date <- sub('-(\\w+) *(\\d{4})-', '-\\2\\1-', data$Date)
```