# Regexp to split month from year in date mmyyyy

Tags: regex, r, date

I have a variable which is the concatenation of month and year, in a numeric format. The month is in format 1-12, not 01-12.

My variable looks like:

```
mmyyyy
12014
22014
102014
52015
112015
```

I am looking for a regexp to match the month or the year only:

for year, I did something like:

```
year <- ifelse(grepl("2014", mmyyyy), 2014, ifelse(grepl("2015", mmyyyy), 2015, 2016))
```

But for the month, I am struggling. My first thought is to replace 2014, 2015, etc. by blank then to convert the result in numeric.

```
month <- as.numeric(gsub("[[^2014]]", "", mmyyyy))
```

but here, I can't find a suitable regexp expression.

In the end, I would like a variable/ vector with the numeric year(yyyy) and a variable/vector with the numeric month.

Comment: Sorry, what is your desired output?

Comment: I want a variable year and a variable month.

Comment: Are your values are of numeric class or a character?

Comment: @Daid: numeric, but I could change the format if needed.

Comment: Have you tried sth like `(?m)(?<month>\d+)(?<year>\d{4})$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is

```
# for the months:
> as.numeric(gsub("(.*)[0-9]{4}$", "\\1", x))
#[1]  1  2 10  5 11
# for the years:
> as.numeric(gsub(".*([0-9]{4})$", "\\1", x))
#[1] 2014 2014 2014 2015 2015
```

This works for any 4-digit years.

Comment: @PalashKumar, `[0-9]{4}$` represents the last 4 numeric digits and `.*` means any characters any number of times. Then, `(...)` is a capture group that you can extreact. In both cases I extract the first capture group but change the place of the `(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution using `tidyr` Which will create both `month` and `year` columns simultaneously in one call.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, mmyyyy, c("month", "year"), "(\\d+)(\\d{4})", convert = TRUE)
#   month year
# 1     1 2014
# 2     2 2014
# 3    10 2014
# 4     5 2015
# 5    11 2015
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(mmyyyy = c(12014,
                            22014,
                            102014,
                            52015,
                            112015))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
mmyyyy <- c(12014,22014,102014, 52015, 112015)
```

Making a 6 digit vector using `sprintf`

```
dates <- sprintf("%06d", mmyyyy)
```

You could use the `yearmon` function from the `zoo` package

```
library(zoo)
dates1 <- as.yearmon(dates, format = "%m%Y")
format(dates1, "%m")
# [1] "01" "02" "10" "05" "11"
format(dates1, "%Y")
# [1] "2014" "2014" "2014" "2015" "2015"
```

**EDIT:** Updated as per @David's comments

Answer (score 1):

You could use the package *unglue* :

```r
df <- data.frame(mmyyyy = c(12014, 22014, 102014, 52015, 112015))
library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(df, mmyyyy, "{month}{year=\\d{4}}", convert = TRUE)
#>   month year
#> 1     1 2014
#> 2     2 2014
#> 3    10 2014
#> 4     5 2015
#> 5    11 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like below (assuming you are only dealing with years > 2000)

```
month <- as.numeric(gsub("20[0-9]+", "", mmyy))
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know how to do REGEX - but heres a simple code. This code will work for all the years until 9999 :)

```
dmmyyyy<-c("12014","22014","102014","52015","112015")
dmmyyyy<-as.character(dmmyyyy)
month <- substr(dmmyyyy, nchar(dmmyyyy)-4+1, nchar(dmmyyyy))
month
[1] "2014" "2014" "2014" "2015" "2015"
```

Answer (score -1):

[Extracting the last n characters from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

Why not to split last characters as year?
see str_sub from stringr package.