# Change column in dataframe based on regex in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with a column displaying different profiles:

```
PROFILE           NTHREADS TIME
profAsuffix       1        3.12
profAanother      2        1.9
profAyetanother   3 
...
profBsuffix       1        4.1
profBanother      1        3.9
...
```

I want to rename all profA* pattern combining them in one name (profA) and do the same with profB*. Until now, I do it as:

```
data$PROFILE <- as.factor(data$PROFILE)
levels(data$PROFILE)[levels(data$PROFILE)=="profAsuffix"] <- "profA"
levels(data$PROFILE)[levels(data$PROFILE)=="profAanother"] <- "profA"
levels(data$PROFILE)[levels(data$PROFILE)=="profAyetanother"] <- "profA"
```

And so on. But this time I have too many differents suffixes, so I wonder if I can use grepl or a similar approach to do the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting the last n characters from a string in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
data$PROFILE <- sub("^([a-z]+[A-B]).*", "\\1", data$PROFILE)
```