# splitting column in R

Tags: r, brackets

I'm facing the following problem. I've got a table with a column called `title`.

The `title` column contains rows with values like `To kill a mockingbird (1960)`.

So basically the format of the column is `[title] ([year])`. What I need are two columns: `title` and `year`, `year` without brackets.

One other problem is that some rows contain a title including brackets. But 
basically the last 6 characters of every row are year wrapped in brackets.

How do I create the two columns, `title` and `year`?

What I have is:

```
Books$title <- c("To kill a mockingbird (1960)", "Harry Potter and the order of the phoenix (2003)", "Of mice and men (something something) (1937)")

title
To kill a mockingbird (1960)
Harry Potter and the order of the phoenix (2003)
Of mice and men (something something) (1937)
```

What I need is:

```
Books$title <- c("To kill a mockingbird", "Harry Potter and the order of the phoenix", "Of mice and men (something something)")
Book$year <- c("1960", "2003", "1937")

title                                             year
To kill a mockingbird                             1960
Harry Potter and the order of the phoenix         2003
Of mice and men (something something)             1937
```

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can work around `substr`ing the last 6 characters.

First we recreate your `data.frame`:

```
df <- read.table(h=T, sep="\n", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
text="
Title
To kill a mockingbird (1960)
Harry Potter and the order of the phoenix (2003)
Of mice and men (something something) (1937)")
```

Then we create a new one. The first column, `Title` is everything from `df$Title` but the last 7 characters (we also remove the trailing space). The second column, `Year` is the last 6 characters from `df$Title` and we remove any space, opening or closing bracket. (`gsub("[[:punct:]]", ...`) would have worked as well.

```
data.frame(Title=substr(df$Title, 1, nchar(df$Title)-7),
           Year=gsub(" |\\(|\\)", "", substr(df$Title, nchar(df$Title)-6, nchar(df$Title))))


                                      Title Year
1                     To kill a mockingbird 1960
2 Harry Potter and the order of the phoenix 2003
3     Of mice and men (something something) 1937
```

Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `substrRight(df$Title, 6)` in a loop to extract last 6 characters so the year with brackets and save it as new column

[Extracting the last n characters from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r)

Comment: No need to use a loop, `substring()` is vectorised

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Vincent Bonhomme:

I assumue that the data are in some text file that I have called `so.dat` from where I read the data into a data.frame that also contains two columns for the title and year to be extracted. Then I use  `substr()` to separate title from the fixed length year at the end, leaving the () alone as the OP apparently wants them:

```
titles      <- data.frame( orig = readLines( "so.dat" ), 
               text = "", yr = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
titles$text <- substring( titles[ , 1 ], 
               1, nchar( titles[ , 1 ] ) - 7 )
titles$yr   <- substring( titles[ , 1 ], 
               nchar( titles[ , 1 ] ) - 5, nchar( titles[ , 1 ] ) )
```

The original data can be removed or not, dpending upon further need.