# Parse text with separator depending on its structure

Tags: r

My dataframe:

```
>datasetM
                                 Mean
ENSORLG00000001933:tex11     2500.706       
ENSORLG00000010797:         44225.330       
ENSORLG00000003008:pabpc1a  11788.555       
ENSORLG00000001973:sept6     3100.493      
ENSORLG00000000997:          5418.796
```

Output needed:

```
>out
[1] "tex11" "ENSORLG00000010797" "pabpc1a" "sept6" "ENSORLG00000000997"
```

I tried this, but I only retrieve the part before the separator:

```
titles <- rownames(datasetM)
vapply(strsplit(titles,":"), `[`, 1, FUN.VALUE=character(1))
```

*Note: There is not logic in the alternance of ENS000:name and ENS00:*

*Note 2: ENSOR are rownames*

*Note 3: When there is nothing after ":" I want the ENSOR*

Comment: so when there's nothing after : then you need the ENSOR... right?

Comment: Yes exactly, hope it's clear enough

Comment: Those are rownames yes?...not a column

Comment: Yes they are, sorry for not telling I'll update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with **base R**:

```
sapply(strsplit(rownames(df), ":"), function(x) x[length(x)])
# [1] "tex11"              "ENSORLG00000010797" "pabpc1a"            "sept6"             
# [5] "ENSORLG00000000997"
```

Another solution with `sub`, might be simpler:

```
sub("^\\w+:(?=\\w)|:", "", rownames(df), perl = TRUE)
# [1] "tex11"              "ENSORLG00000010797" "pabpc1a"            "sept6"             
# [5] "ENSORLG00000000997"
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "                                 Mean
ENSORLG00000001933:tex11     2500.706       
ENSORLG00000010797:         44225.330       
ENSORLG00000003008:pabpc1a  11788.555       
ENSORLG00000001973:sept6     3100.493      
ENSORLG00000000997:          5418.796", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
```

Comment: I tried an alternative ```sapply(strsplit(rownames(df),split = ":"),function(x){ifelse(length(x)==2,x[2],x[1])})```

Comment: @amrrs Sure that works too, but don't you think mine is simpler :)

Comment: Indeed, That's why didn't add a separate answer :p

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vectorized way to do this using a regex (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18732853/5635580)) to identify the last character of each rowname,

```
 rownames(df)[!sub('.*(?=.$)', '', rownames(df), perl=TRUE) == ':'] <-
       sub('.*:', '', rownames(df)[!sub('.*(?=.$)', '', rownames(df), perl=TRUE) == ':'])
```

which gives,

> ```
>                            V2
> tex11                2500.706
> ENSORLG00000010797: 44225.330
> pabpc1a             11788.555
> sept6                3100.493
> ENSORLG00000000997:  5418.796
> ```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(V2 = c(2500.706, 44225.33, 11788.555, 3100.493, 
5418.796)), .Names = "V2", row.names = c("tex11", "ENSORLG00000010797:", 
"pabpc1a", "sept6", "ENSORLG00000000997:"), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**NOTE** You can remove the colons from rownames simply by

```
rownames(df) <- sub(':', '', rownames(df))
```